# How to install mapper attachment plugin in windows

Tags: elasticsearch

How do I install mapper attachment plugin in windows
.I downloaded the plugin from this link:
    https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch-plugins/mapper-attachments/mapper-attachments-5.2.2.zip.

what to do next?
Help?

Answer (score 0):

You can go to elastic search folder, then follow the below command
go to path in cmd then type `elasticsearch-plugin install file:\\\mapper-plugin file path.zip`

`.zip` at the end is must.